# Symfony 5.1 Deprecation RouteCollectionBuilder -> RoutingConfigurator

Tags: symfony, updates, deprecation-warning, symfony5

I am updating a Symfony project from 5.0 to 5.1
There is this one deprecation hint saying `RouteCollectionBuilder` is deprecated and `RoutingConfigurator` should be used instead.

The exact message is

> Since symfony/routing 5.1: The
>   "Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder" class is
>   deprecated, use
>   "Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator"
>   instead.

How is this supposed to be implemented?
Am I supposed to change code in the vendors folder?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to update `Kernel` class to start using `RoutingConfigurator` instead of `RouteCollectionBuilder`.

You can do it automatically by updating the recipe (`composer recipes:install symfony/framework-bundle --force`).

Comment: Just be aware that the 5.1 Kernel.php was also changed to only load yaml config file.  If you happen to use php or xml config files then you need to make a few additional tweaks.  You also risk overwriting any changes you may have already made to Kernel.php.  An alternative approach is to create a fresh 5.1 project and then do a bit of diff/copy/pasting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answere. I did not change Kernel.php so far so that's OK and also I strictly used yaml for configuration. However the recipe update changed some other files too which I have to review. Looks very promising though :-)

Comment: ....and to provide another hint: the project dir method has vanished from the original kernel. That has caused problems for me

Comment: took me 5 minutes to figure out that RoutingConfigurator::import() method has a different signature than previous RouteCollectionBuilder::import() method. $prefix param is gone ;-)

Answer (score 14):

If anyone has problems fixing this depreciation

```
Since symfony/routing 5.1: The "Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder" class is deprecated, use "Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator" instead.
```

Here is my updated file `src/Kernel.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\Configurator\RoutingConfigurator;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    protected function configureContainer(ContainerConfigurator $container): void
    {
        $container->import('../config/{packages}/*.yaml');
        $container->import('../config/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');

        if (is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.yaml')) {
            $container->import('../config/services.yaml');
            $container->import('../config/{services}_'.$this->environment.'.yaml');
        } elseif (is_file($path = \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/services.php')) {
            (require $path)($container->withPath($path), $this);
        }
    }

    protected function configureRoutes(RoutingConfigurator $routes): void
    {
        $routes->import('../config/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/*.yaml');
        $routes->import('../config/{routes}/*.yaml');

        if (is_file(\dirname(__DIR__).'/config/routes.yaml')) {
            $routes->import('../config/routes.yaml');
        } elseif (is_file($path = \dirname(__DIR__).'/config/routes.php')) {
            (require $path)($routes->withPath($path), $this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From Symfony 5.4 onwards, accordingly to the symfony/framework-bundle recipe, Kernel.php can be empty like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;
}
```

Source recipe:
https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/5.4/src/Kernel.php

For some reason, applying the recipe (`composer recipes:install symfony/framework-bundle --force`) didn't updated the kernel file. But by replacing it with the above content, worked for me and fixed the deprecation warning.

Comment: Confirmed to be working with ^6.1 components

Answer (score 2):

Symfony has a demo project on GitHub which is perfect to checkout changes like that without having to create a new local project.

Just have a look at the [reworked Kernel.php](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/main/src/Kernel.php) and update the entire content, not just the `RoutingConfiguration` which will lead to other errors that routes can't be found.